# based on true and false value how should i make visibility of button true in xml file only using kotline

Tags: kotlin

See the below code the apply_job value might be true or false

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/apply_job"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Apply"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: in xml you can use `android:visibility` attribute to set visibility of a widget. If you want to dynamically change visibility of a widget you need to do it from code (using kotlin/java)

Comment: actually i am using recycler view and to show button i get true values and false to not show the button

Comment: do you have one button or *n* buttons?

Comment: n number of buttons

Comment: check this [recycler view tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html#kotlin). You can use `onBindViewHolder` method in your adapter to set visibility of your buttons.

Comment: override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
          holder?.button?.text =jobData.submit
    } how should i write here because i get the true and false value when i hit my api url

Comment: i was assuming you had some array/list in your adapter with true/false values. In that case you would just set the visibility with `holder?.button?.visibility = yourList[position]`. But now I don't understand your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin, you don't have to initialized variables if you are using kotlin extensions.

Make sure you have added this plugin in your module's *build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Manage the visiblity

```
val canShow = true
apply_job.visibility = if(canShow) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
```

Comment: but how should i use it in xml file like in angular we use ng_show = "apply_job" in button tag property

Comment: @zebapathan If you want to manage the visibility directly in XML, you have to use **Data Binding**. Check this out [Android DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

Comment: You don't need to include a separate plugin for Kotlin Android Extensions anymore (in fact, it can cause issues). It's included in the regular Kotlin Gradle plugin. You just need to apply it with `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`.

Comment: i am new to kotline. please give me this data binding with an example

Comment: @zebapathan You can check the link in my above comment. It will be very lengthy to explain it here.